# Travelling Pakistan from USA and Dubai Visa

Tags: transit-visas, dubai, pakistani-citizens, emirates

I am traveling through Emirates airlines from USA to Pakistan next month with my wife and daughter. I am **green card** holder with **Pakistani passport**, wife with **Pakistani Passport** is going Pakistan to be interviewed for immigration and my daughter is **US citizen**.

Now we have 14 hours layover in Dubai and want to go out of airport to meet family in Dubai/Abu Dhabi. Based on above information, are we eligible for visa on arrival? If not, what are our options?

Comment: Consult with [Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/us/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=PK&NV=Pakistan&AC=US&AV=United+States&DC=PK&DV=Pakistan&TC=AE&TV=United+Arab+Emirates&h=f15c802df5e1931c5f58beddc41310a3bdd2c7); my search on its tool indicates you and your wife are eligible for Transit Without Visa (TWOV) for max 24 hours.

Comment: @Dorothy I did the same and it sounds like you are right. You get contradictory answer from Emirates. Is there any case you are aware of where visa was issued on arrival?

Comment: That I don't know, but I would suggest that you contact Emirates now and see what it responds.... a google says it's $58 per person and if you can't get complimentary visas with Emirates, me, I'd get them... writing it off the cost of avoiding a terrible hassle... But, your US residence seems to be the magic key.. Is your return to the US on Emirates, too?

Comment: Yes, my return is through Emirates too. Can you please tell where exactly you got $58 price? I would also prefer them instead of being uncertain of what possibly can happen on arrival.

Comment: Now [VFS is showing $44](http://www.dubaivisa.net/online/duration96hours.html) per person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You and your wife both need visas. You can ask your travel agent to apply for a paper visa which takes 24hrs-5days depending on what service you choose. You can simply print your visa and present it to the immigration authorities in Dubai.

You can also check with Emirates if they will provide you with a complimentary visa.

Comment: Me and my wife need visa, I get that part. Do we qualify or can we buy visa at the airport? I read somewhere (may be at Emirates website), they charge $48 per person for 96 hours visa.

Comment: No. Pakistani passport holders required a visa prior to to boarding.

Comment: I was able to get visa on arrival at Dubai airport but it was expensive comparative to buying prior to traveling.

Answer (score 0):

As your transit is less than 24 hours, you do not need a visa for Dubai in order to board your flight.

Dubai allows visa free transit for those with less than 24 hours of transit time.

As you would like to leave the airport, the best option is to apply for a visa through Emirates directly. This is cheaper than getting it on arrival and will take but a few days (if that) since Emirates will effectively be your "sponsor" for the visa.

You and your wife need visas, your daughter is exempt.

Enjoy your flight.

Comment: Is this something recent? Last year when I went there I had to purchase visa on arrival.

Comment: You only need a visa if your transit is more than 24 hours, or you are switching airports or otherwise want to visit the city. Otherwise you don't need a visa if you will remain in the airport for the duration of your transit.

Comment: You could always get a visa through Emirates and on arrival as well. The costs are different. They have also started the e-visa service now so you can pre-arrange your visa.